# difference between desktop application and web application in android

Tags: web-applications, desktop-application, mobile-application

as my question may be very easy to answer. but some days before i was discussing my android project with my friend. He said that you are developing a mobile desktop application. I said him that no my app will be a web application.

- In my project basically i m using the web services and POSTING the request to server and displaying the response in my app after parsing. now i m little bit confuse that should i call this app as a web application or mobile web application or something like that.
- I want to know the actual difference between the Desktop app, mob app, web app.

Hope for positive response. Thanks.

Regards
Qadir Hussain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think the desktop apps are only the one that will not connect to the internet
or the world wide web whatever if its networked or not
but the wep app is the one that will contact the internet or world wide web by 
any mean.
regarding the mobile app this is the one that will run in a mobile device.

Answer (score 2):

A desktop app runs on a stationary machine, or a laptop. On what we call "a computer".

A mobile app is designed to run on mobile devices such as mobile phones or tablets - although they technically are computers as well- but have limitations when it comes to storage, connectivity, etc. The mobile app runs on the mobile device.

A web app runs on a browser. If this browser runs on a mobile device or a desktop computer, it's still a web app.

If you coded your application to run on the mobile using something like Android SDK, then I'd say it's a mobile (native) app. The fact that it connects to a server on the net does not mean necessarily it's a web app. If you e.g. make an app in javascript that runs on a browser, then it's a web app.

I hope it helps =)

Comment: Yes, my app runs on just android phones just like other apps but not on the browser but on back end I m calling web-services. So basically I m doing hand shaking with the web and sending HTTP requests and getting response. so can we not call this a web application.

Comment: I guess there's a thin line there, but I wouldn't call an online game necessarily a "web app", even though it connects to the internet.